# Type of expression's result in C... Integer Promotion and Usual Conversions

Tags: c, types, expression

If hi have , in C, follow expression `a+b`, where

```
signed long a;
unsigned short b;
```

.....
wich is type of result?

I think that is unsigned long for usual conversion... But maybe not...
For a machine with integer on 16 bit, short and long can have also 16 bit... So...

1. For promotion integer `b` is promoted to unsigned int ... And now I have `signed long + unsigned int`.. Not same type...
2. For usual conversion ... we convert signed long and unsigned int in unsigned long (tupe unsigned with rank of signed type)...

So if `a = -10` and `b = 120` , `a + b != 0`... In this case `a + b = (65426)_10`

this is right?

Comment: `long can have also 16 bit` well, it can't. `long` has to at least be able to represent `2,147,483,647`. It has to have at least 32-bits.

Comment: "For a machine with integer on 16 bit, short and long can have also 16 bit" No. `LONG_MAX` must be at least 2^31 - 1, it is not allowed to be smaller than that. Seems all of these misconceptions originate from the impossible "16 bit long".

Comment: @Lundin, probably the same course. :)

Comment: @Devolus Probably not since I wrote that dupe post myself as a self-answered Q&A back in 2017?

Comment: if unsigned short has the same number of value bits as signed long, the result is unsigned long, otherwise the result is signed long.